# HTML align elements in a TD all next to each other

Tags: html, css

i jus added this slider next to a input and added a input box after the slider.  Problem is they are underneath my first input.  I want them all side by side in the TD tag....please help...let me know if you need more code:

```
    <td>$
    <input name="sup" style="text-align: left;" maxlength="13"

                    value="${form.sup}"

            onkeypress="javascript:return noenter();" />
<div id="calcSlider"></div>
<input type="text" id="calcRepairCostFactor" name="calcRepairCostFactor" value="10" size="3" readonly="readonly"/>            
</td>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
$("#calcSlider").slider({ min: 0,
                          max: 90,
                          step: 5,
                          value: 10,
                          slide: function (event, ui) {
                              $("#calcRepairCostFactor").val(ui.value);
                          }
                       });
                    });
```

ANSWER:

```
  <td>$
    <input name="sup" style="text-align: left;" maxlength="13"

                    value="${form.sup}"

            onkeypress="javascript:return noenter();" />
<div id="calcSlider" style='display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 12px;'></div>
+/-
<input type="text" id="calcRepairCostFactor" name="calcRepairCostFactor" value="10" size="3" readonly="readonly"/>            
%
</td>
```

Comment: A `div` inside of a `table td` seems superfluous.  In other words, if your content is already inside of a `div`, there's no reason to keep the `table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much info... I'm guessing you probably need to add `style='display: inline-block;'` to the `div` to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Cool did that....but now the input box right after it is in the same position of the div

Comment: Do you have any CSS relevant to the elements in your question? With no other CSS, you should see something like `input div input` all in a line like that. Are you saying the second input is on top of the div?

Comment: nah they are in the same position meaning the input is literally on top of it

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/tbXDG/1/ Copy and paste of your code with inline-block on the div, then I gave the div width/height and a background so you can see it. Are you using a jQuery plugin? If so, that's very relevant information and should be in your question.

Comment: Thanks...your styling helped it look good....just had to increase the width.....thanks